# tkinter.root.destroy and cv2.imshow - X Windows system error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, opencv, python

I found this rather annoying bug and I couldn’t find anything other than a unanswered question on the opencv website, hopefully someone with more knowledge about the two libraries will be able to point me in the right direction.
I won’t provide code because that would be beside the point of learning what causes the crash.

If I draw a tkinter window and then `root.destroy()` it, trying to draw a `cv2.imshow` window will result in a X Window System error as soon as the `cv2.waitKey` delay is over. I’ve tried to replicate in different ways and it always gets to the error (error_code 3 request_code 15 minor_code 0).

It is worth noting that a `root.quit()` command won’t cause the same issue (as it is my understanding this method will simply exit the main loop rather than destroying the widgets). Also, while any `cv2.imshow` call will fail, trying to draw a new tkinter window will work just fine.

What resources are being shared among the two libraries? What does `root.destroy()` cause in the X environment to prevent any cv2 window to be drawn?

Debian Jessie - Python 3.4 - OpenCV 3.2.0

Comment: If cv2 is trying to draw into the window, or creates a child of the root window, then it's reasonable for it to throw an error when you destroy the root window.

Comment: It’s not being drawn on tkinter’s root window, root window is what tkinter.Tk() returns, and that’s all I’m destroying. Or is it?

Comment: When you destroy the root window, all child windows are destroyed too.

Comment: If you already have a tkinter GUI, then display the image using Tk as well. It's quite simple to implement and a lot less hassle than making two GUI toolkits play together nicely in a single app.

Comment: I have a bunch of utils I’ve written which are cv2 based, rewriting the methods for tkinter would be a hassle I couldn’t bother with.

Comment: I don't understand the comment "rewriting the methods for tkinter". If you don't need tkinter, why create the root window in the first place? If cv2 needs tkinter, then why is it a hassle to use tkinter?

Comment: I’m using cv2 to grab a roi and a couple fast previews, tkinter comes into play when I need the user to review the data extracted from the image. This is not what I was asking anyway so please let’s not focus on this, my problem is with cv2 and tkinter clashing and that is regardless of my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy the root window, it destroys all children windows as well. If cv2 uses a tkinter window or child window of the root window, it will fail if you destroy the root window.

Comment: Oh... so cv2 uses tkinter to display images? What am I supposed to do then? Is there any way to destroy the tkinter window I’m drawing without interfering with cv2’s ability to draw a window on its own?

Comment: Side note for clarification: what I’m calling root can be called anything, I’m creating that window with my call to tkinter.Tk() and that simply seemed to be the naming convention in most tutorials.